# Add a class in all the elements of selector get by class in angular2

Tags: angular, class, angular2-template, elementref

I am getting a element ref by below code and I want add a class and remove a class from all the elements which i get.

app.component.html

```
<ul>
   <li class="option-btn cm-grey" />option 1</li>
   <li class="option-btn cm-grey" />option 1</li>
   <li class="option-btn cm-grey" />option 1</li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
var allbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.option-btn');
allbtn.removeClass('cm-grey');
allbtn.addClass('cm-blue');
```

Above code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use classlist

```
allbtn.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Note: The classList property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9. The following code will work in all browsers:

```
function myFunction() {
    var element, name, arr;
    element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    name = "mystyle";
    arr = element.className.split(" ");
    if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        element.className += " " + name;
    }
}
```

Similarly

```
allbtn.classList.remove("mystyle");
```

Cross-browser solution

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.className = element.className.replace(/\bmystyle\b/g, "");
}
```

You can further pass class names to these functions as a parameter if you want to go for cross-browser support (which I encourage) and make these functions reusable.

Comment: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element>'. - this error is coming when I use classlist

Comment: This is not good practice to use direct document in angular like :
document.getElementById("myDIV")

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.option-btn'); returns an array you need to iterate on that array to be able to use classList. @AMitSiNgh

Comment: please mention how to iterate and use the class list. @gurmeet

Comment: I have provided pure js functions for cross-browser you can convert them by reading through the code and creating a function according to your own needs @AMitSiNgh

Comment: [].forEach.call(allbtn,function(key,value){ 
 key.classList.remove("cm-grey");
});